# Importing Networkx

Tags: pypy

I run my python script using pypy as pypy file.py Graph ....
Then I got trace back error as follows

import networkx as nx
ImportError: No module named networkx

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install networkx`?

Comment: Yea. Tried python -m pip install networkx but its not working

Comment: You're not going to get any help this way. We don't know what issues you ran into when trying to install networkx. Have you installed other modules before? Did it work? What is the difference when you try to install networkx? How are you running your script? Can you succesfully import other modules in your script? See also: [What do you mean it doesn't work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)